# How to use UIStepper in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uistepper

How to use UIStepper Control in an IOS Application. I am using monotouch, C# and examples i have seen are not of c#. the following code doesn't show anything.

```cs
 UIStepper stepper = new UIStepper();
 var section = new Section();
 section.Add(stepper);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going:

```cs
var stepper = new UIStepper(new RectangleF(50, 50, 100, 50));
stepper.MinimumValue = 0;
stepper.MaximumValue = 10;
View.AddSubview(stepper);
stepper.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine(stepper.Value);
```